# Is it possible to write several members in a class in the same line in F#?

Tags: .net, f#

I currently have the following code:

```
let private matchers = [|
    { new Matcher() with
        member __.RegexExpr = RegexExpr("^(let)")
        member __.TokenTypeCreator _ = TokenType.LET }
|]
```

and I was wondering whether it would be possible to write it all in the same line. Something akin to the (non-working):

```
let private matchers = [|
    { new Matcher() with member __.RegexExpr = RegexExpr("^(let)"); member __.TokenTypeCreator _ = TokenType.LET }
|]
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing F# object expression in one single line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873206/writing-f-object-expression-in-one-single-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot find a syntax to do it either. It is possible to declare an interface on a single line by simply putting nothing between the members:

```
type IFoo = abstract member A: int abstract member B: int;;
```

But if I try the same to instantiate it, the compiler refuses it:

```
  { new Foo with member this.A = 1 member this.B = 2 };;
  ---------------------------------^^^^^^

stdin(10,34): error FS0010: Unexpected keyword 'member' in expression. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other token.
```

I have to say I sometimes wish F# had a single consistent rule to desugar indentation-based code, like Haskell does.