# F# Multiple expressions on one line

Tags: syntax, f#

I am aware of another [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873206/writing-f-object-expression-in-one-single-line) but it does not exactly answer my specific issue.

I am trying to write a let statement, which in idiomatic F# would require several indented lines, into a single-line statement.

E.g. how to write the following function as a single-line statement:

```
let fn (x: double) = let fn1 (x1: double) = x1 + 1.0
                     let fn2 (x2: double) = x2 + 2.0
                     // ... possibly more lines
                     2.0 * (x |> fn1 |> fn2)
```

The only solution I found is rather convoluted, with nested `in` statements :

```
let test1 (x: double) = let fn1 (x1:double) = x1 + 1.0 in (let fn2 (x2: double) = x2 + 2.0 in 2.0 * (x |> fn1 |> fn2))
```

I was hoping that I could get rid of the nested `in`s and instead use semicolons to separate the inner statements, but it does not seem to work:

```
let test2 (x: double) = let fn1 (x1:double) = x1 + 1.0; let fn2 (x2:double) = x2 + 2.0; 2.0 * (x |> fn1 |> fn2)
```

My question: can I write a multiple statements expression on a single line without using the nested `in` statements?

Comment: and you don't want to use lambas?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer; not that I know of

Bit longer answer;

In F# `;` is a way to combine two expressions (every computation in F# is an expression, there are no statements) and throw away the first result. If it was a function it could been defined as this:

```
let (;) a b = b
```

In F# "variable declaration" is an expression and the original ML syntax is `let x = <y> in <z>` meaning in the scope of the `z` `x` is set to the value of `y` expression. Many years, ago the `#light` syntax was introduced in F# to make `in` optional when you could use intendention to infer the correct meaning. The `in` syntax is still preserved in the cases where you like to do it in a single line.

In other languages "variable declaration" is a statement updating the list of visible variables in that scope, not so in ML like languages.

That every computation is an expression is a major appeal to me for F# over "normal languages" that relies on statement and expression to express computations.

While I doubt this is what you are looking for you can write the oneliner above more succinct:

```
  let test1 x = let fn1, fn2 = (+) 1.0, (+) 2.0 in x |> fn1 |> fn2 |> (*) 2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the trick by making a tuple of your required functions then pipelining them into a next function which calculates the final result:

```
let test x = ((+)1.0, (+)2.0) ||> fun f1 f2 -> x|>f1|>f2|>(*)2.0
```

By this way, you don’t need to use the `let` and `in` keywords.